# android studio - default constructor?

Tags: android, constructor, default

I need your help. I created an app in Android Studio, then I created a second "page", well I created a second class.
But it says this class needs an default constructor. What shall I do?

I hope you can help.

Cheers

Comment: what is your class name?

Comment: you should create a default constructor I guess

Comment: SlideToUnlock is the name of the class

Answer (score 0):

Follow a tutorial if you are new to Android Development.

https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1670

Could help you understand the flow better. Google is your friend, don't be afraid to search if you need tutorials.